# IS there any way to simulate tablet 8" (2560 x 1600) in RWD mode with proper scaling in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Can I somehow simulate the 8 inch tablet( 2560 x 1600 pixels, 16:10 ratio (~359 ppi density) ) with big native resolution on RWD mode In Firefox or Chrome? I tried with setting DPI in devtools to 3 without any effect. Maybe there is smarter way to do it?
If that helps the application is ionic 3 for tablets. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "without any effect"? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I expected it will shrink to fit my screen to my resolution (1920x1080).